# Change node path to current directory

Tags: node.js

I was trying to run this command from my user directory

```
NODE_ENV=~/Public/project node socket.js
```

But it return this error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/socket.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

The thing is i do not want to change directory. Is it possible to do that? And why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little mor research, i found [this](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files)

And according to that site, i have to do this

```
export NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/home/user/Public/project/config
```

and run this

```
node ./Public/smart-backwall-server/socket.js
```

Answer (score 0):

NODE_ENV is, by convention, the type of environment you're running in, e.g. Development or Production or Test.  It only matters for modules that inspect it and set options accordingly, e.g. Many loggers will default to more verbose in development.

Not really sure why you wouldn't just change directories, but your call to server.js can be an absolute or relative path.  If the file is in the /home/user/project folder, you can (from /home/User) just call

node ./project/socket.js

Comment: it gave me this `WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/user/config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.` after running node./Public/project/socket.js. Nodejs supposed to found config file inside ~/Public/project but it return that